# forwardInvocation: the return value gets lost

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, message-forwarding

I want to use message-forwarding on my SZNUnmanagedReference class. It has this properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *authors;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SZNReferenceDescriptor *referenceDescriptor;
```

Basically, when an instance of UnmanagedReference receives the message `authorsString`, it should forward it to `referenceDescriptor`, which has a method named `- (NSString *)authorsStringWithSet:(NSSet *)authors`.

So, i wrote this in `SZNUnmanagedReference.m`:

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {

    SEL aSelector = anInvocation.selector;

    if ([NSStringFromSelector(aSelector) isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(authorsString))]) {
        NSMethodSignature *signature = [self.referenceDescriptor methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(authorsStringWithSet:)];
        NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
        NSSet *authors = [NSSet setWithSet:self.authors];
        [invocation setSelector:@selector(authorsStringWithSet:)];
        [invocation setArgument:&authors atIndex:2];
        [invocation setTarget:self.referenceDescriptor];

        [invocation invoke];
    } else {
        [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:aSelector];
    }
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if ([super respondsToSelector:aSelector]) {
        return YES;
    } else if ([NSStringFromSelector(aSelector) isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(authorsString))] && [self.referenceDescriptor respondsToSelector:@selector(authorsStringWithSet:)]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
    if (!signature) {  
        signature = [self.referenceDescriptor methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(authorsStringWithSet:)];
    }
    return signature;
}
```

It all seems to work, the code in the `SZNReferenceDescriptor` class gets executed.
However, I don't know how to get the `authorsString` back. If I understood the documentation correctly, I think the `referenceDescriptor` is supposed to send the result back to the original sender of the message. But it doesn't seem to work. In my test class, `[unmanagedReference authorsString]` returns `nil`.

Comment: Are you sure you need message forwarding here?

Comment: Now that you mention it, probably not… I might have got a bit carried away. I guess I could have implemented `authorsString` so that it would do  `return [self.referenceDescriptor authorsStringWithSet:self.authors];`

Comment: Yes; you only need forwarding if you can't know at compile time what messages you want to respond to and how -- since you are always doing the same thing, forwarding seems like overkill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're constructing a new `NSInvocation` object, whose return value isn't accessible at the point where it's needed (the "top" of the message dispatch "stack"). The runtime only knows about the one that it created for you (the argument to `forwardInvocation:`; that's the one whose return value it will use. All you have to do, then, is to set *its* return value:

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {

    if (anInvocation.selector == @selector(authorsString)) {
        id retVal = [self.referenceDescriptor authorsStringWithSet:self.authors];

        [anInvocation setReturnValue:&retVal];   // ARC may require some memory-qualification casting here; I'm compiling this by brain at the moment
    } else {
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
    }
}
```

In fact, there's actually no need to create that new invocation; since all you need is the return value of the method, you can just send the message directly (which you could also do if you just implemented `authorsString` on `SZNUnmanagedReference`, rather than using the forwarding mechanism).

Also, note that there's no need to convert selectors to and from strings in order to compare them -- `SEL`s can be compared directly using the equality operator.

Comment: Works great, thanks a bunch! Also, I shouldn't have overloaded `- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector`, right?